# How do you store arrays into a JSON object?

Tags: java, json, jsonp, org.json

I have a the following objects:

- `server`:  a string
- `products`:  will be arrays within the server
- `productProperties`:  will be an array within a product

Is the following a correct way to store the value in a JSON format?

```
JSONOBJECT jmap = new JSONOBJECT();


jsonArray jproduct = new jsonArray ();


jsonArray jproductsProperty1 = new jsonArray ();
jproductsProperty1  .put("P1");
jproductsProperty1  .put("P2");

jsonArray jproductsProperty2 = new jsonArray ();
jproductsProperty2  .put("Q1");
jproductsProperty2  .put("Q2");


jproduct.put(jproductsProperty1);
jproduct.put(jproductsProperty2);
jmap.put(server,jproduct);

out.print(jmap.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

first argument its just a key and second its your object could be a collection like a array

```
JSONOBJECT jmap = new JSONOBJECT();

jsonArray jproductsProperty1 = new jsonArray ();
jproductsProperty1.put("P1");
jproductsProperty1.put("P2");

jsonArray jproductsProperty2 = new jsonArray ();
jproductsProperty2.put("Q1");
jproductsProperty2.put("Q2");

jmap.put("jproductsProperty1", jproductsProperty1 );

jmap.put("jproductsProperty2", jproductsProperty2 );
```

Comment: can you please answer according to object names i specified...that will be helful

Comment: but this data is not according to the server . Actually server is a key and according to server the products are there....by your code i will get this response {"jproductsProperty2":"Q1","Q2"],"jproductsProperty1":["P1","P2"]}   but server is nowhere here this complete data will be in one server say server1. how to achieve that ?

Comment: Thanks for your help..your code help me to get the answer..i think i have to use two JSONOBJECT  in my case..i pasted the answer..thanks.

Comment: well you just asking how store array into jsonobject i was not sure what you where looking for exactly but it look like you found a answer

Answer (score 0):

okay i think i need to use two maps here .....like this

```
JSONObject jmap1 = new JSONObject();

    JSONObject jmap2 = new JSONObject();

    JSONArray jproduct = new JSONArray();


    JSONArray jproductsProperty1 = new JSONArray();
    jproductsProperty1  .put("P1");
    jproductsProperty1  .put("P2");

    JSONArray jproductsProperty2 = new JSONArray();
    jproductsProperty2  .put("Q1");
    jproductsProperty2  .put("Q2");


    jproduct.put(jproductsProperty1);
    jproduct.put(jproductsProperty2);
    jmap2.put("jproductsProperty1", jproductsProperty1 );

    jmap2.put("jproductsProperty2", jproductsProperty2 );
    jmap1.put("A",jmap2);
    System.out.println(jmap1);
```